# how to add entry in ingress-nginx conf file using helm chart

Tags: nginx, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

Want to add the below entry in ingress-nginx conf file:

`limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m rate=30r/m;`

nginx.conf should look like:

```
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m rate=30r/m;

  server {
  # ...
   location /login.html {
       limit_req zone=one;
  # ...
  }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you want to do it via helm chart, anyway there are three ways to customize NGINX ingress:

1. [ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/): using a Configmap to set global configurations in NGINX.
2. [Annotations](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/): use this if you want a specific configuration for a particular Ingress rule.
3. [Custom template](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/custom-template/): when more specific settings are required, like [open_file_cache](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#open_file_cache), adjust listen options as rcvbuf or when is not possible to change the configuration through the ConfigMap.